# Plotting 3d from different Excel Files

Tags: tikz-3dplot, excel2latex

i have several Excel Files (.csv) which are built up like the following scheme:

`Instruction Averange ddv
500 6717.10 300
600 7572.30 300
[...]`

So basicalle the column "Instrcution" is the same in every Excel File.
"Dependency Degree (aka ddv)" runs from 0 to 500 in 50 steps.
I now want to plot a 3d plot looking like this:

[image]

It is a picture of a very [Similar Problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211267/problem-with-plotting-3d-plot-in-latex-i-have-a-sample-matlab-plot) but i cant adjust their solution to my problem.
The Code i got so far is this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={Instructioncount},
ylabel={Degree of Dependence},
zlabel={Lines of Code},
]
\addplot3 [surf] table[x = Instruction, y = ddv, z = Average, col sep = semicolon] {Compiler_Benchmarks/CodeLengthAfterCompiling_350.csv};
\addplot3 [surf] table[x = Instruction, y = ddv, z = Average, col sep = semicolon] {Compiler_Benchmarks/CodeLengthAfterCompiling_300.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

That results in:
[image]

Basically "all i want" is to get latex to combine both separate lines in a area and not only two independent lines.
I added both example Excel-files:
[Excel Files](https://ftp.tu-ilmenau.de/index.php?id=428df509425dfe82149fe4325baf3695&login=cf1cf66e600ed913e484267f68e67434)
Basically i just want tex to draw a countinous area between both lines so that it looks like a area.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Most likely this is due to your data. Could you append a small sample to your question?

Comment: I uploaded both files: https://ftp.tu-ilmenau.de/index.php?id=428df509425dfe82149fe4325baf3695&login=cf1cf66e600ed913e484267f68e67434

Comment: To me your data seems to be one-dimensional. That is, for every `x` value, there is one `y` and `z` value. You are using two separate plots. In the linked answer it is discussed how to create *one* data file instead. I guess you should do that here, too.

Comment: @marmot i dont know how to properly merge them automatically with latex, because in the linked example it seems that he has 3 files: 1 for x,y and z. But i have mutliple files (10) that all share praticalley 1 axes and differ in the other 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the two tables to a new table, which needs to be sorted. I also changed the view and personally I'd also rotate the axes labels, but this is up to you.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188492/121799
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\output}{Compiler_Benchmarks/CodeLengthAfterCompiling_350.csv} % loads `CodeLengthAfterCompiling_350.csv' -> `\output'
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\output}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval} % finds number of columns
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\output}{Compiler_Benchmarks/CodeLengthAfterCompiling_300.csv}% appends the entries of CodeLengthAfterCompiling_300.csv to output
\pgfplotstablesort{\sorted}{\output} % sorts the entries
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={-35}{35},
xlabel={Instructioncount},
ylabel={Degree of Dependence},
zlabel={Lines of Code},
xlabel style={sloped like x axis},
ylabel style={sloped},
]
\addplot3 [surf,mesh/rows=\numrows,shader=faceted, faceted color = none] table[x = Instruction, y = ddv, z = Average, col sep =
semicolon] \sorted;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another Question: is it possible to delete the \output table after the use ? I got weird problems with "lstlisting" because it adds the first line of output in the text bevor the listing.

Comment: @Incanus How would I know? I do not know what your document looks like. Just try to put `\def\output{}` after the plot, I guess it will work.